# Agent does not seem to have access to workspace in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, windows-server-2019

When running on an agent instead of the default Jenkins controller, I'm unable to read and write to files in env.WORKSPACE, but I can read and write to files specified to the UNC path on the server agent. I'm attempting to clone a directory from git, read from a file in the cloned directory, write to the file, then commit and push these changes in my Jenkinsfile. The agent is executing on Windows Server 2019. While this workaround to work with this file in the UNC server path is fine for just changing one file once in my script, I don't want to have to navigate this issue when I need to modify many different things in the future.

Originally I tried this:

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'myAgent' }
    environment {
        FILE = "myFile.ini"
    BUILD_FOLDER = "${env.WORKSPACE}\\myRepo\\someFolder\\"
    BUILD_FILEPATH = "${BUILD_INI_FOLDER}" + "\\${FILE}"
    }
    stages {
        stage ('Setup') {
            steps {
                //Tried with and without these commands
                bat """
                    rmdir /s/q "${env.BUILD_FOLDER}"
                    mkdir "${env.BUILD_FOLDER}"
                """
                gitClone("sshPathToRepo", "myRepo")
           }
        }
        ...
        stage ('Postbuild') {
            steps {
                value = readValueFromFile("${env.BUILD_FILEPATH}")
                ... //modify the value
                writeValueToFile("${env.BUILD_FILEPATH}", value)
                bat """
                cd "${env.BUILD_FOLDER}"
            git add ${env.FILE}
            git commit -m "Increment build number _"
            git push
        """
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then readValueFromFile and writeValueToFile expand to

```
//FilePath is path passed to the function
File file = new File(FilePath)
def lines = file.readLines()

for (line in lines) {
...
```

The repo is cloned with no issues, but attempting to readValueFromFile produces a "file not found" error, but when I display the contents of the path with dir, the file is clearly there. No issues when running on Built-In Node default Jenkins environment.

I had to change to something like this for it to work:

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'myAgent' }
    environment {
        FILE = "myFile.ini"
    BUILD_FOLDER = "${env.WORKSPACE}\\myRepo\\someFolder\\"
    BUILD_FILEPATH = "${BUILD_INI_FOLDER}" + "\\${FILE}"
    }
    stages {
        stage ('Postbuild') {
            steps {
                agentWorkspace = ""
        def iniFolder = "${env.BUILD_FOLDER}"
                if ("${env.BUILD_FOLDER}".indexOf('JenkinsRemote',0)){
            iniFolder = "${env.BUILD_FOLDER}".replace("F:", "\\\\${NODE_NAME}\\f\$")
        }   
        
        pathToIni = "${env.BUILD_FILEPATH}"
        if ("${env.BUILD_FILEPATH}".indexOf('JenkinsRemote',0)){
            pathToIni = "${env.BUILD_FILEPATH}".replace("F:", "\\\\${NODE_NAME}\\f\$")
            agentWorkspace = "\\\\myAgent\\f\$\\JenkinsRemote\\workspace\\myPipeline\\"
        }
                bat """
                    rmdir /s/q "${iniFolder}"
                    mkdir "${iniFolder}"
                """
                gitClone("sshPathToRepo", "${agentWorkspace}\\myRepo")
                bat """
            pushd "${iniFolder}"
            git checkout main
            popd
        """

                value = readValueFromFile("${pathToIni}")
                ... //modify the value
                writeValueToFile("${pathToIni}", value)
                bat """
                pushd "${iniFolder}"
            git add ${env.FILE}
            git commit -m "Increment build number _"
            git push
                    popd
        """
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong or is there a way around this?